# HTTP request that throws a null exception

Tags: android, httpresponse, isnull

I have an activity that create a new instance of connection. like this:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.daily_news);

    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new SwipeGestureDetector());
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tx);
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(myActivity.this, "","Validating user...", true);
    connection con = new connection(dialog);
    final String str =con.connect_to_db("http://10.0.2.2:8000/daily/my.php");

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            tv.setText(str);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });        
}
```

}

in connection class i have an HttpResponse that returns null. like this:

```
public class connection {

private HttpPost httppost;
private HttpClient httpclient;
private HttpResponse response;
private ProgressDialog dialog = null;
private String result;

 public connection(ProgressDialog di){
     dialog = di;
 }
public String connect_to_db(String url){

    try{            
        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new HttpPost(url); 
        response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        result = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
    }catch(Exception e){
        dialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

why the value of "result" in connection class is null?

Comment: Check the host, port and whether the server is visible from the phone (given the ip it might be that it is not). Also verify that the request for this url path is really a post request.

Comment: And please follow the general naming conventions in java: classes starting with caps, methods and variables camel cased.

Comment: Have you set Internet permission in Manifest? ALso please check if respon,se is also null

Comment: I'm surprised! I create new project and put them in it and it worked correctly.

Comment: Is an exception thrown in the `connect_to_db` method? An exception would be indication which causes result to be null.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
 final String str =con.connect_to_db("http://10.0.2.2:8000/daily/my.php");
```

Should not be written in the onCreate, but rather in a separate thread => NetworkOnMainThreadException

For your NullPointer, please tell us if you have the Internet permission in Manifest and if response is null or not.

Comment: when i check my code, it runs until
        "httppost= new HttpPost(url);" and after that,go into Exception.

Comment: Which exception is thrown? What is the stacktrace or the message?

Comment: in my logcat print"Exception:null".

Comment: Try `e.printStackTrace()` in your exception handler. The exception will help you to find the line of code which fails and why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

May be because you are doing network operation in onCreate Method. It will not create any problem if you are using android2.2, but if it is  HoneyComb then chances are that it is causing some exception and finally you are getting null value. Move the code to onResume() method.

For Simplicity use

HttpResponse response =  httpclient.execute(httppost);

and

```
String valueString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
int  statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

print these values and see the out put.